# Application.exe has encountered a issue and needs to be closed error at the time of Application Launch

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp

I have made a windows form application using Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7.Every thing is working fine into my System.I have build the application on Visual studio 2010 and it is ok.Application.exe is getting created under the Bin in Release Mode of the Visual Studio.
Now i am trying to launch this application On Clients PC which is Windows XP but it is giving following.

> Application has encountered a problem and needs to be closed.we are sorry for inconvenience.

I am not getting the reason for this.Please help .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look at the Application Event Log (start, run, eventvwr) and see if there are details to the exception.

Comment: Are you running Symantec Endpoint Protection?

[Previous Case Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08533576-ffda-4fbe-8cce-21d0a88dcd53/exename-has-encountered-a-problem-and-needs-to-close-we-are-sorry-for-the-inconvenience?forum=winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1:** i'm suspecting that the `.NET Framework` version with which you built the Application is heigher than what client is using.

**Solution 1:** try to build your appliction with the client compatible `.NET Framework` version.

**Problem 2:** You might be building your application with `X64` option in build settings.

**Solution 2:** change the `Platform Target` of the Application from `X64` to `X86` from buid settings and rebuild your application.

Comment: Which .net Version is used in VS2010

Comment: @Pranav: goto project properties-> Appliction-> now check Platform Target

Comment: then check the client version.

Comment: There also its 2.0 only.How to check Platform Target and change from X64 to X86

Comment: @Pranav: goto project properties-> Build-> now check Platform Target

Comment: Its Any CPU option .Do i need to update it to the stated by you ie. X86 then will it run?

Comment: change it to  x86 and rebuild?

Comment: Will You please tell me what is x86 and what is the difference between  Any CPU and x86.Also my client machine is running Windows Xp and i think its its 32 bit machine

Comment: it is to set the target framework so that works on different frameworks, if it is set to X64 it works on 64 bit OS, and if set to X86 works only on 32 bit pc, but if it is set to AnyCPU works asper client msachine but it some times does not work for x86 os IMO