# My application works on my PC (Windows 7) but not another (XP) and I am not sure how to continue diagnosing the issue

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, exception

**Problem Context**

I have been developing a database application on my PC (Windows 7, using Visual Studio 2010 Express), and it has been working as expected. I just copied the latest version on to a PC running Windows XP and it throws the `"Program has encountered an error and needs to close"` error message.

The info in the error message within the Application Event Log showed that the error is occurring in `initializeDatabaseConnection()` (according to the stack trace) - this is a fairly short method, which only contains a few lines of code.

```
dbConnection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=myserver; 
                                                           uid=myuser; 
                                                           pwd=mypassword; 
                                                           database=mydatabase;");
dbCommand = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();
dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection;
```

---

**Steps taken to attempt to diagnose the problem**

- I added a `try-catch` to the code within `initializeDatabaseConnection()` to catch any `Exception` and call `MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()` - the same error as before occurs and it does not show the message box. It says there is an *unhandled* exception, despite showing this method in the stack trace.
- I added a more specific handler to the `catch` block, one for `System.IO.FileLoadException` which is the specific error message the event log entry describes. The same behavior occurs as for a generic Exception handler as above.
- I found a question on Stack Overflow which described an issue where an application worked as expected until moved to a different machine which suggested Visual Studio Remote Debugging - however as I use Visual Studio 2010 *Express* according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(v=vs.100).aspx) this is not a feature available to me.
- A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098580/application-exe-has-encountered-a-issue-and-needs-to-be-closed-error-at-the-time) on Stack Overflow suggests, as a first step, to check the version of the `.NET Framework` the application is targeting is not higher than the other PC can handle. I switched it down as far as `3.5` and the same error still occurred, and I am confident the other PC has run many `4.0` applications anyway.
- The [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098580/application-exe-has-encountered-a-issue-and-needs-to-be-closed-error-at-the-time) suggests that you check the platform you are building for in `Build Settings` to confirm it is set to `x86` - I have done so, and it is.
- I added an Unhandled Exception Event Handler as suggested by Aybe which shows that the issue is `Could not load file or assembly, MySql.Data ... etc.` ... *however* I'm unsure why this error would be occurring suddenly, as previous versions of the build worked as expected.

---

**Solution**

- The version of `MySql.Data.dll` the application required was `6.8.3.0` however the one in the folder was `6.9.3.0` - I'm not sure why it required `6.8.3.0` now as the version in the application folder on the client PC has not been changed and `6.9.3.0` was working with previous builds.

I discovered this thanks to a comment below suggesting I implement an `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` and linking to documentation for how to do it. This was a feature of the CLR I was not previously aware of. Thank you!

Comment: If my question is unclear or inappropriate I would really appreciate some advice to improve it, please. It's frustrating to see downvotes etc. and not understand what is wrong with my question, as far as I can tell it meets the requirements for SO and I have done as much research as I can. Thank you :)

Comment: Two tips : did you try to catch the unhandled exception (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ? Visual Studio Community is available for free, if you can afford the switch you'd get new features.

Comment: Yes, I did. Well, I'm reasonably certain I did - the stack trace shows that the exception occurred in `initializeDatabaseConnection()` and (as I described above) I used a `try-catch` in there but it still showed 'unhandled exception' in the event log entry, oddly.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a VM with that environment along VS so you can debug the problem more easily/efficiently ?

Comment: @Aybe Ah I see what you mean - I have added an Unhandled Exception handler as you recommend. Thank you! I am not sure how it can be unhandled though, if the code in the method (`initializeDatabaseConnection()`) is all inside a `try-catch`, though?

Comment: These exceptions are signals of an irrecoverable error, you should be able to (at least) prevent such situation or warn the user upstream/within your code. Hence the suggestion of debugging within that environment, you'll know exactly what happens and could take necessary measures to avoid such exception.

Comment: @Aybe Thank you for your help. If you'd like to put the suggestion of implementing an `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler` as an answer I would be more than happy to accept it. I was not aware of this functionality.

Comment: If you found a solution, add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am still not sure why the Exception was unhandled (as, according to the Application Event Log entry' stack trace the exception occurred in a method in which all code was encapsulated by a generic Exception `catch`-block), I was able to, in effect, catch the unhandled Exception by using an `UnhandledExceptionEventHandler`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException 
      += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler); 
}

static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception) args.ExceptionObject;
    // Do what you like with the exception 
}
```

Comment: You weren't able to catch the exception in the code because the exception was occurring when the JIT compiler attempted to *compile* that method - so none of your code (including any `try`/`catch` blocks) ever started running. A `try`/`catch` at a higher level than that method should (I think) have been able to catch it, but not a block *within* the method that's failing to compile.